# Is there a way to get Opsworks deploy through cache and not by cloning?

Tags: chef, chef-solo, opsworks

Is there a way to get opsworks to deploy by doing `git pull` instead of `git clone` every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting this in custom JSON did the job -

```
{
  "deploy": {
     "my_app_name": {
        "delete_cached_copy": false
     }
   }    
}
```